# Definite integral with power series

Tags: integration, power-series

I need to approximate the following integral with six exact decimals using power series:

$$\int_{0}^{0.2} dx/(1+x^5) $$

What I have so far :

$$\int_{0}^{0.2} dx/(1+x^5) = (0.2)-(0.2)^6/6+(0.2)^{11}/11- ... $$

But the answer in the manual is 0,044522 so I must have done something very wrong here...

Comment: The answer in the manual is wrong.

Comment: What you did is very correct and the book is wrong. By the way, welcome to the site.

Comment: Thanks to both of you :)

Comment: Answer is 0.199989335194742

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power series for $f(x)=1/(x+1)$ is
$$ f(x)=\frac1{x+1} = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + \cdots $$
and thus
$$ f(x^5) = \frac1{x^5+1}=1-x^5+x^{10}-x^{15}+\cdots. $$
Therefore, the integral becomes $\int_0^{1/5}f(x^5)dx$, which is
$$\begin{split}
\int_0^{1/5}f(x^5)dx & = \int_0^{1/5}(1-x^5+x^{10}-x^{15}+\cdots)dx\\
& = x -\frac16x^6+\frac1{11}x^{11}-\frac1{16}x^{16}+\cdots\bigg]^{1/5}_0\\
& = \frac15-\frac16\left(\frac15\right)^6+\frac1{11}\left(\frac15\right)^{11}-\frac1{16}\left(\frac15\right)^{16}+\cdots.
\end{split}$$
This is indeed the same as what you got. You are right; the answer book is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the series
$$\frac 1 {1+x}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^n$$ Let $x=t^5$ to make
$$\frac 1 {1+t^5}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^n t^{5n}$$ Integrate termwise
$$\int \frac {dt} {1+t^5}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{t^{5n+1}}{5n+1}$$ This is an alternating series, so you need $p$ such that
$$\frac{(0.2)^{5p+6}}{5p+6} \leq \epsilon$$ I do not think that you need many terms.